# Rainbow Door Sequence

Tags: logical-deduction

I have 7 doors coloured like the rainbow:

[image: #Rainbow doors]

You can move in either direction moving one door for the first go, two for the second, three for the third, etc - you get the idea.

**NOTE**

You *can* jump to the other side. e.g. On your first go you can move from red to violet.

Start on red. Is it possible to go to each door, only going to each colour door no more than *twice*? (It is impossible to do it touching each one just once)

You must end up back on red

What is the sequence of movements which will result in success? (I am looking for the least amount of moves)

The current leader board, top 5:

1. Matt: 9
2. Oren Melzer: 9
3. Matt: 13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verified by computer program, the optimal solution is

> 9 steps

This can be done four ways, but they are all rotations/reversals of Matt's answer.

> LRLRLRLLL
>
>  LRLRLRRLL
>
>  RLRLRLLRR
>
>  RLRLRLRRR
>
>
>  Many longer solutions exist, up to 13 steps, without hitting the same spot more than twice.

Answer (score 5):

**More Efficient**

Alternate left and right until you've visited all, then head straight for red

> RLRLRLRRR

This will traverse:

> Red -> Orange -> Violet -> Yellow -> Indigo -> Green -> Blue -> Blue -> Indigo -> Red

**Old Answer**

Okay, since we have to go back to the end, add a move left or right (lands back on Indigo, since we're at 7 now), then do the above moves in reverse.

> RRRLLL L LLLRRR

This will go back to indigo and then touch the other six doors once, ending on red. The final progression:

> (Start) Red -> Orange -> Green -> Violet -> Yellow -> Blue -> Indigo -> Indigo -> Blue -> Yellow -> Violet -> Green -> Orange -> Red

Comment: I am afraid you do have to go back to red, nice try though!

Comment: I'll edit the puzzle to make that clearer

Comment: Sure. It's trivially easy to backtrack and end back on where you started.

Comment: Faster way added in.

Comment: Well done! I'll accept this unless someone can do this in less than 13 moves

Comment: How about 9? :)

Comment: Added you to the new leaderboard in my question

Comment: alright @Matt - you are currently my star student. As an extension - can you get a number smaller than 13 but not just doing alternating movements? :)

Comment: I can prove that 9 is the fewest. Getting to each door takes at least 7, on the 7th you can't move, so winning in 8 requires the 7th door to be adjacent - let's pick orange.  You get to orange from a door that's 6 away - but not red.  It must be yellow.  You get to yellow from 5 away - but again, not red, so this must be blue.  Let's track from the beginning now - we move 1 from Red, but not to orange, so this is violet.  Then we move 2, but not to orange again, so we end up on blue.  Thus blue is used twice (moves 2 and 4) as *well* as orange, a contradiction with only using eight moves.

Comment: Confirmed by brute-force enumeration.  There are 8 solutions for 9 moves.